# How to implement a basic Analyzer in Lucene 4.2.1?

Tags: java, apache, search, lucene

Lucene 4.2.1 doesnot have StandardAnalyzer, and I am not sure how to implement a basic analyzer that does not alter the source text. Any pointers?

```
final SimpleFSDirectory DIRECTORY = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File(ELEMENTS_INDEX_DIR));
IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_42, new Analyzer() {
        @Override
        protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s, Reader reader) {
            return null;
        }
    });
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(DIRECTORY, indexWriterConfig);
    List<ModelObject> elements = dao.getAll();
    for (ModelObject element : elements) {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new StringField("id", String.valueOf(element.getId()), Field.Store.YES));
        document.add(new TextField("name", element.getName(), Field.Store.YES));
        indexWriter.addDocument(document);
    }
    indexWriter.close();
```

Comment: I am also really confused.. all I need is standard analyzer. even the demo in the 4.2.1 source uses StandardAnalyzer but would not compile (cause it's looking for it in org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer which does not exist anymore)

Answer (score 9):

You have to return a TokenStreamComponents from createComponents.  `null` is not adequate.

However, Lucene 4.2.1 certainly **does** have [StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html).

If you are, perhaps, refering to the changes in StandardAnalyzer in Lucene 4.x, and are looking for the old StandardAnalyzer, then you'll want [ClassicAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/ClassicAnalyzer.html).

If you really want a trimmed down Analyzer that doesn't modify anything, but just tokenizes in a very simple fashion, perhaps [WhitespaceAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html) will serve your purposes.

If ou don't want it modified or tokenized at all, then [KeywordAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordAnalyzer.html).

And if you must create your very own Analyzer, as you say, then override the method `createComponents`, and actually build and return an instance of [`TokenStreamComponents`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents.html).  If none of the above four serve your needs, I have no idea what your needs are, and so I won't make an attempt a specific example here, but here is the example from the [Analyzer docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html)

```
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
 @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer source = new FooTokenizer(reader);
    TokenStream filter = new FooFilter(source);
    filter = new BarFilter(filter);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
  }
};
```

There is a single arg ctor for TokenStreamComponents as well, so the filter is optional, by the way.

Comment: This did not solve the problem and StandardAnalyzer doesn't seem to be usable. How do I instantiate it? Can you post a sample code file that uses analyzer and works with Lucene 4.2.1?

Comment: "If none of the above four serve your needs, I have no idea what your needs are" +1!

Answer (score 2):

You should add the Common Analyzers to your project. 
They are now available in a separate JAR file in the Lucene-4.2.1.zip file under "analysis/common".

```
 lucene-analyzers-common-4.*.jar
```

Once you add it to your project (as you added the core) you should have this working:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
```